# Proving that the CMBR remains thermal after a Lorentz boost

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, cosmology, inertial-frames, cosmic-microwave-background

Suppose $S$ is a frame in which the CMBR is thermal and isotropic. I'm taking this to mean it follows the Planck Blackbody distribution $$n(\omega)=\frac{1}{\pi^2 c^3}\frac{\omega^2}{e^{\beta\hbar\omega}-1}$$
where $n(\omega)$ is the number density of photons with frequency $\omega$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{k_B T}$.

Now let $S'$ be another inertial frame moving with velocity $v$ relative to $S$. I want to show that the CMBR will also appear thermal in $S'$, but with an anisotropic temperature.

My attempt is this: Let $\theta'$ denote the angle between $v$ and a particular photon's $p$. The frequency in the frame $S'$ is $\omega'$ where $\omega=\gamma(1-\frac{v}{c}\cos\theta')\omega'$.

We have that $$Vn(\omega)d\omega=V'n'(\omega')d\omega'$$ (working with the total number $N$ rather than density to factor in lorentz contraction). Then $$n'(\omega')=\frac{V}{V'}n(\omega(\omega'))\frac{d\omega}{d\omega'}=\gamma^2(1-\frac{v}{c}\cos\theta') n\left(\gamma(1-\frac{v}{c}\cos\theta')\right)$$
which gives
$$n'(\omega')=\gamma^4(1-\frac{v}{c}\cos\theta')^3\frac{1}{\pi^2c^3}\frac{\omega'^2}{e^{\beta'\hbar\omega'}-1}$$
where $\beta'$ is given by $$T'(\theta')=\frac{T}{\gamma(1-\frac{v}{c}\cos\theta')}.$$

My expression for the temperature appears correct, but I have this factor of $\gamma^4(1-\frac{v}{c}\cos\theta')^3$ which I don't think should be here.